# 100 doors problem solution does not work as expected

Tags: c

This question will be about 100 doors problem which is a famous problem from rosetta. Here is the problem:

- There are 100 doors in a row that are all initially closed.
- You make 100 passes by the doors.
- The first time through, visit every door and  toggle  the door  (if the door is closed,  open it;  if it is open, close it).
- The second time, only visit every 2nd door  (door #2, #4, #6, ...),   and toggle it.
- The third time, visit every 3rd door   (door #3, #6, #9, ...), etc,   until you only visit the 100th door.

**The question:** what state are the doors in after the last pass? Which are open, which are closed?

So my point is give program an input ,lets say n, so after nth pass which doors will be open kind of thing but there is a flow in it and I could not find it. If there is anyone who can correct issues of my logic I would be happy. Thank you all.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 1;

int main(){
    int doors[101];
    int i,j,x,b;

    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(j=1;j<=x;j++)
    {
        for(i=j;i<=100;i=i+j)
        {
            if(doors[i] == 0)
            {
                doors[i]==1;
            }
            else
            {
                doors[i]==0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(b=1;b=100;b++){
        if(doors[b]==1)
        {
            printf("%d\n",b);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quite a few big problems. 1.`doors` is being used whilst uninitialised. 2. `{doors[i]==1;}` should be `{doors[i]=1;}`

Comment: For the final `for` loop, `b=100` should be `b<=100`.

Comment: OT: Arrays in C start at index zero. You can make your arrays 1 bigger than needed and only use from index 1 and up but ... If you want to be a C programmer you better get used to start from zero. No company will accept your coding style!

Comment: @4386427 It depends. If it makes the code simpler (and smaller), there is not much harm in leaving `doors[0]` unused and starting at 1.

Comment: Also: you could use boolean for `doors[]` and toggle with `doors[i] = !doors[i]`, and `if(doors[i])`.

Comment: @IanAbbott There are always exceptions to "general rules" (even to the "never use goto" rule). But having index 0 to represent the first item is very fundamental in C and for this program there seems no significant gain in doing anything else.

Comment: You read in `x`. I guess it is supposed to be the number of doors (!?) but still you hard code the other loops to 100

Comment: @4386427 Well you'd need to add or subtract 1 in a couple of places. E.g. `for(i=j-1; i<100; i++)` and `printf("%d\n", b+1);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Adding a 1 a few places is IMO not enough to break the fundamental rule that array indexing start at zero

Comment: @4386427 I think `x` is just supposed to be the number of passes.

Comment: @IanAbbott The number of passes must be equal to the number of doors. That's how the puzzle works. If you don't you won't get the "funny" output: 1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2, ..  (i.e. 1 4 9 16 25 ...)

Comment: Actually my idea about array index was : I though them as doors, and since there is no 0th door I wanted 1 more array element then 100 and do not use the 0th at all. Also ı thought uninitilizing the array give all elements automatically zero.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there were a few errors in your code:

```
int doors[101];   // uninitialized array. You want int doors[101] = {0};
...
        if(doors[i] == 0)      // ok == for a comparison
        {
            doors[i]==1;       // NO! an assignation is expected: doors[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            doors[i]==0;       // id.: doors[i] = 0;
        }
...
for(b=1;b=100;b++){            // NO! a comparison is expected: for(b=1;b<=100;b++)
```

This is enough to get the sequence of perfect squares: 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100.

But you consistently use your array starting from index 1 which is an antipattern in C language. Your code could be simplified into:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NDOORS 100

int main() {
    int doors[NDOORS] = { 0 };

    for (int j = 1; j <= NDOORS; j++)
    {
        for (int i = j-1; i < NDOORS; i += j)
        {
            doors[i] = 1 - doors[i];
        }
    }

    for (int b = 0; b <= NDOORS; b++) {
        if (doors[b] == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", b+1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61366204/4386427 is the answer to accept as it explains the problems in the code and provide a solution.

I just want add that the problem is about the number of times you toggle a door.

If you toggle it an even number of times, the door will still be closed at the end.

If you toggle it an odd number of times, the door will be open at the end.

This comes down to the number of divisors a door number has, i.e. even number of divisors or odd number of divisors.

Example:

```
14 have the divisors 1, 2, 7, 14 That's an even number so door 14 is still closed

16 have the divisors 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 That's an odd number so door 16 will be open
```

The only numbers that have an odd number of divisors are square numbers.

Therefore you can simply do:

```
int numDoors = 100;
for (int i=1; (i*i) <= numDoors; ++i) printf("%d\n", i*i);
```

It's simple, fast, and without arrays - but requires that you know the puzzle in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

A Simple ruby code for this problem would be:

```
LEN = 100
array = [false] * LEN
(1..LEN).each do |pass|
  (-1..LEN).step(pass).each do |i|
    next if i == -1
    break if i >= LEN
    array[i] = !array[i]
  end
  # puts "Pass: #{pass}"
  # puts "Gates: #{array.inspect}"
end

array.count(true)
```

Output: 10

Answer (score 0):

solution  in java

```
public class Door100 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int doors[]= new int[100]; //this is our 100 doors
   //cheaking condition
    for(int i=1;i<=doors.length;i++){
       int j = i;
       while(j<doors.length){
        if(doors[j]==0){
            doors[j]=1;
        }
        else{
            doors[j]=0;
        }
        j += i;
       }
       //desired outputO(open doors)
    }
    for(int i=0;i<doors.length;i++){
        if(doors[i]==1)
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).